# Are my results realistic or is there an error somewhere?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, mathematical-modeling

The background is that I'm solving a problem in Numerical Analysis which I asked about here: [Is my derivate correctly programmed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283183/is-my-derivate-correctly-programmed)

Now if I use the new code, then I get a result that is along the expectations ("You should find that the depth at xf = 25 nautical miles is close to 2500 feet.") but why is the sound wave changing direction, it seems like it is first travelling downward, then upward and then changing direction again. Is that really realistic for a sound wave under the water or do I have an error somewhere in my model?

[image]

Comment: You know, you could include all the details of your problem in your question. If someone is willing to help, making him/her go through another question (without details), which links to a book, is not really appealing. Make your question self-contained, so that someone looking at it can understand what you ask without going through other sites/books.

Comment: I might have a solution for you, but I need to test it on my MATLAB machine. I'll let you know in a couple hours.

Comment: This sort of behaviour is common for sound waves under water. Read about the SOFAR channel:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOFAR_channel

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose it is ok to state that the sound wave appears to change direction several times from looking at the graph. This was puzzling me and I'm glad for the link @NickThompson thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have validated your solution with the following code:

```
p1 = -20.2090;
p2 = 17.3368;
p3 = 272.9057;
beta = 7.8*pi/180;
x0 = 2000;

c = @(z)4800+p1+p2*z(1)/1000+p3*exp(-.75*z(1)/1000);
cp = @(z)(p2/1000-.75/1000*p3*exp(-.75*z(1)/1000));
q0 = (c(x0)/cos(beta))^2;

ode = @(t,z)[z(2); -q0*cp(z)/c(z).^3];
IC = [x0; tan(beta)];
[x,z] = ode45(ode,[0 25*6076], IC); 
plot(x,z(:,1))
```

As far as it being physically meaningful, I do not know. Nevertheless, the code above matches your paper and the solution it yields matches as well.

Comment: It is physically meaningful, and a known environmental issue. It is the reason why the US Navy and geophysical exploration companies have been accused of making marine mammals going deaf. This behavior cause the wave to propagate essentially in 2D and reduces the decay by an order. So sounds are loud in the channel miles away.

Comment: @NickThompson Interesting to know, thanks :)

Comment: Very good answer and comments. I worked long to understand my results because it didn't look right that the wave changed direction when looking at the depth and the x-axis for the sound. I think this was an interesting exercise that also had meaningful physical interpretation.